# Как пишутся программы-ассемблеры?

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Пишу свою собственную программу-ассемблер для своего собственного языка ассемблера. Пишу на C++. Получается вот что то такое:

```
void createMachineCode(string& path) {
ofstream out(path, ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);
int machineCode;

for (int instr = 0; instr < assemblyProgramm.size(); instr++) {

    if (isIType(assemblyProgramm[instr][OPCODE_POS])) {
        if (isICorrect(assemblyProgramm[instr])) {
            machineCode = convertIToMachineCode(assemblyProgramm[instr]);
        }
        else {
            compiledStatus =  "syntax error on line: " + to_string(instr + 1);
            return;
        }
    }
    else if (isRType(assemblyProgramm[instr][OPCODE_POS])) {
        if (isRCorrect(assemblyProgramm[instr])) {
            machineCode = convertRToMachineCode(assemblyProgramm[instr]);
        }
        else {
            compiledStatus = "syntax error on line: " + to_string(instr + 1);
            return;
        }
    }
    else if (isJType(assemblyProgramm[instr][OPCODE_POS])){
        if (isJCorrect(assemblyProgramm[instr])) {
            machineCode = convertJToMachineCode(assemblyProgramm[instr]);
        }
        else {
            compiledStatus =  "syntax error on line: " + to_string(instr + 1);
            return;
        }
    }
    else if (isRTType(assemblyProgramm[instr][OPCODE_POS])) {
        if (isRTCorrect(assemblyProgramm[instr])) {
            machineCode = convertRTToMachineCode(assemblyProgramm[instr]);
        }
        else {
            compiledStatus = "syntax error on line: " + to_string(instr + 1);
            return;
        }
    }
    else if (isUType(assemblyProgramm[instr][OPCODE_POS])) {
        if (isUCorrect(assemblyProgramm[instr])) {
            machineCode = convertUToMachineCode(assemblyProgramm[instr]);
        }
        else {
            compiledStatus = "syntax error on line: " + to_string(instr + 1);
            return;
        }
    }
    else {
        compilingErrorsStatus = 0;
        compiledStatus = "syntax error on line: " + to_string(instr + 1);
        return;
    }

    out.write((char*) &machineCode, sizeof machineCode);
    machineCode = 0;

    if (instr == assemblyProgramm.size() - 1) {
        int temp = 0;                                            // last command - halt.
        out.write((char*)&temp, sizeof(int));
    }
}

out.close();

compiledStatus = "program compiled successfully\n";
}
```

Это главная функция, в которой и происходит весь парсинг. Получается довольно примитивно. Я проверяю какого типа команда, смотрю корректен ли ее размер, дальше проверяю операнды и в конце-концов записываю ее как последовательность нулей и единиц в бинарный файл. Не уверен, но что то мне подсказывает, что в реальности это происходит совсем не так. Информации по тому, как пишут реальные ассемблеры не нашел. Но не всегда же берут какой то язык и пишут на нем компилятор для какого-то другого языка? Как бы тогда написали самый первый язык?)

Comment: Почему минусуете? Мне кажется, что данный вопрос весьма интересен.

Comment: Первый транслятор написали, понятно, в машинных кодах.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал вам почитать "Компиляторы" Ахо-Ульмана-Сети-Рави.

Comment: Возможно я невнимательно смотрел этот фрагмент кода, но что-то я тут в упор не вижу даже намеков на обработку символьных адресов (имен "переменных" и меток (в т.ч. точек входа в функцию)) и соответственно построения таблицы, которая позволит 1) сделать правильные относительные адреса для ссылок вперед и 2) далее позволит линкеру связать вместе объектные файлы (результат работы ассемблера) и далее 3) настраивающему загрузчику разместить программу в реальной памяти и передать ей управление.

Comment: @avp, метки - это команды типа J. Функция которую я привел - это самый верх. Дальше у меня команды каждого типа парсятся по особому, эти функции я уже не выкладывал.

Comment: Видимо я просто не понимаю, какой у вас набор команд или что вы называете ассемблером, но такое впечатление, что в файл out помещаются только 4-х байтные machineCode. Я могу допустить, что все адреса к которым обращается программа на вашем ассемблере д.б. определены до первой инструкции и эта глобальная таблица известна в функциях convert... / Но  каким образом тут реализуются переходы вперед?

Comment: Ворох if-else-if уже настораживает. Сделали бы функцию определяющую тип команды, в зависимости от типа из таблицы обработчиков команд взяли бы сходу адрес нужной функции (благо они у вас они все одинаковые) и вызвали. А вообще пишутся так, как пишутся. Одно и то же можно сделать десятками разных способов, вопрос лишь в правильности выходного результата и скорости работы

Comment: @avp зависит от модели языка, тот же brainfuck два прихлопа три притопа.

Comment: @MolbOrg, все зависит от того, что называть ассемблером. Последовательно развивая Вашу мысль bash тоже будет можно назвать ассемблером.

Comment: @avp https://gergo.erdi.hu/blog/2013-01-19-a_brainfuck_cpu_in_fpga/
Подождем пока баш реализуют в железе, я в принципе возражать не буду)), хотя и не назову это лучшим выбором.

Comment: @MolbOrg,  развлекаются же люди! `Lava → VHDL → Xilinx` что же, это уже в самом деле интересно. Возможно, не так и долго осталось до времени, когда компайлеры будут производить объектный код для построения на FPGA оптимальной для компилируемой программы вычислительной структуры.

Comment: @avp именно именно